# How to show subtitles outside of Youtube player?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I have SRT file for embeded youtube video on my website and I want to have a table under player container with 2 columns: one for English subtitles and second is for translated subtitles.

I need to hightlight subtitles in both columns, but for this I need to catch event when new subtitle starts.

Is there a way to feed youtube player with SRT file and then catch events every time player starts new subtitle ?